# How can we get the removed value from onChange event in react js without using event.target.value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
passwordCheck = (event) => {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent, event.nativeEvent.srcElement);
    let confirmPass;
    if (event.nativeEvent.inputType === "insertText") {
      this.state.checkConfirm.push(event.nativeEvent.data);
      confirmPass = this.state.checkConfirm.join("");
    } else if (event.nativeEvent.inputType === "deleteContentBackward") {
      console.log("confirm check", this.state.checkConfirm);
       this.state.checkConfirm.pop();
      confirmPass = this.state.checkConfirm.join("");
    }
    console.log(confirmPass);
    this.setState(
      {
        rePassword: confirmPass,
        starRepassword: event.target.value.length,
        passwordErrors: "",
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.newPassword === this.state.rePassword) {
          console.log("matched");
        } else {
          this.setState({
            passwordErrors: `passwords do not match`,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<input className="form-control custom_input d-flex      justify-content-center"
                type="text"
                id="rePassword"
               
                autoComplete="off"
                placeholder="*******"
                
                value={"*".repeat(this.state.starRepassword)}
                
                onChange={(e) => this.passwordCheck(e)}
              />
```

Here I am trying to check password but my password should be in "*" characters so in else if condition I am trying to get removed character but I am failing to do it Can anyone suggest me the approcah

Comment: why you don't use input with type  ='password' ?

Comment: @barzin.A I cannot use type="password" As I need stars("*") in my input box

Comment: I don't understand , type='password' show * when user type in it and you can read input's value easily

Comment: @barzin.A It will show circle shape It will not show any  * astreik if you can do it share any example